# Google Apps Domain for WordPress

Tags: google

I'm very much a novice with this, therefore I'm initially looking for some advice and steer with integrating Google Apps with WordPress.

I bought my domain via GoogleApps. I want to use WordPress and my CMS, however I'm not sure how to get started in using my GoogleApps domain for WordPress. When a user types the domain into their browser, I want them to land on the WordPress site with the domain still in the browser. For example, if they type www.example.com they go to the WordPress site and www.example.com displays in the browser.

Is this possible? Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: So, do you want a Website built with WordPress? You need a hosting where WordPress is installed; buying a domain is not enough to have a website.

Answer (score 1):

Jamie, do you already have hosting for your WordPress site? And to be specific, is your WordPress site self-hosted, or are you using WordPress.com?  If I understand your question correctly, you will need to point the domain name you purchased to your hosting/server.

Depending on where you are hosting your site, you may have access to cPanel, Plesk or some other dashboard which will allow you to change DNS settings. This is where you make the domain name point to the IP address of your server. Once this change has been made, it propagated or works its way through the internet, so that when you type the domain name it finds your website. The initial email you received when you signed up for hosting should tell you how to get to your dashboard.

If you site is hosted on WordPress.com, look for using Domain Mapping in the support area - https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question Ray and apologies for asking such a basic question.

The site is currently hosted on WordPress.com, therefore I will look into using Domain Mapping.

Thank you again.

Best wishes,

Comment: Jamie - You're welcome. You've got to get your basic questions answered before you can get to the big ones. Once you get your feet wet on WordPress.com, c'mon over to the .org side---the water's fine!